# What is the difference between "K extends keyof T" and "K extends keyof T = keyof T"?

Tags: typescript

The original question is here.
https://tsch.js.org/8/play

The answer is

```
type Exclude<T, K> = T extends K ? never : T
type MyReadonly2<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  readonly [P in K]: T[P]
} & {
    [L in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[L]
  }
```

Instead of

```
type Exclude<T, K> = T extends K ? never : T
type MyReadonly2<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  readonly [P in K]: T[P]
} & {
    [L in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[L]
  }
```

I am confused about the "= keyof T" here
What is the difference of with or without it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it gets a default value when it is not specified. This applies to any generic.

This is no different than a default value for an optional param in a function.

According to your reqs all keys must be made readonly when the second generic param is not specified. By adding `K extends keyof T = keyof T` you accomplish exactly this. If someone uses your type, but only specifies one type, then the keys are taken as all keys of `T`.

Here are the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand why I got confused. Because the question has a test case goes "Expect<Alike<MyReadonly2<Todo1>, Readonly<Todo1>>>,", and wants me to implement something like the official Readonly, which doesn't have a required type input as K

Answer (score 0):

`MyReadonly2<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>`

The bit after `=` is the default. This way you don't have to specify `K`, you can declare a variable `let foo: MyReadonly2<SomeInterface>`, it'll default to `keyof SomeInterface`.